# Wake on lan on raspberry pi 4 with ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: server, raspberrypi, wakeonlan

I am making a media server on my raspberry pi 4 but I don't have any cooling case for it yet, so I decided to turn it on when I need it and off when I don't,in order to prevent overheating. But my raspberry pi is in other room than my TV and I would like to be able to turn my raspberry pi on and off with just my phone.

Comment: Wake on lan is not any kind of remote control. If the network card supports it a magic packet is sent to it and that wakes it up. I do not think there is any way to send a magic packet from a phone to a network device.

Comment: @David Thank you very much for your quick reply and clarification, I am relatively new to this scene and wasn't sure about it.